# Unable to get Root folder location of the ASPNET CORE Web Application from a referenced DLL

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a ASPNET Core Web Application which references a library that is generated from another .NET Core project.
Is there a way to programmatically get the root folder location from within the referenced library?
I am not able to use the ContentRootPath API in the project that generates the library because it is NOT a Web Application.

ASPNET Core web application details :
Target Framework = .NET Core 3.1

Referenced Library details.
Target Framework = .NET Standard 2.1

Comment: How do you connect the library to the app? Are you utilizing dependency injection?

Comment: what do you mean by _"the root folder location"_? content root (i.e. where ASP.NET core serves static assets) or the location of its EXE/DLL file or the folder that contains the source code?

Comment: My answers : (1) I am using Visual studio to develop my ASPNET CORE web app, I am using the library just by adding it as a reference in the dependencies section of the solution.   (2) : root folder location is the location where appsettings.json and web.config files are present. for eg : In my windows machine, My application name is Webapplication , so the root folder location is : **C:\Users\username\source\repos\WebApplication\WebApplication**

Comment: I am not using dependency injection, I just want to fetch the root folder location inside referenced library, because i have to process information of files present inside root folder of ASPNET CORE web app.

Comment: Basically I want customer to use my library with their ASPNET CORE web app, and my library should process information of files present inside their ASPNET Core web app's root folder

Comment: Ok, a couple of points: 1. Consumers of your library can set the content root to any path they want. If you want to access it, you need to get its runtime value, to do that, that value has to flow from ASP.NET Core to your library. You can't just reach to a global object and get the path, because ASP.NET Core doesn't save that path to anywhere. You need to connect your library to ASP.NET Core using dependency injection, or take the path as a parameter in one of your classes and force the consumer to supply it.

Comment: Using dependency injection is the recommended way of connecting libraries to receive information from the framework. If you don't want your consumers to write a boilerplate code to use your library, you can hide all that cruft behind a shiny extension method on `IServiceCollection` and none the wiser.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using dependency injection, you can pass the content root to the library when you're registering it in DI:

```cs
services.AddTransient<MyLibType>(provider =>
{
    var contentRoot = provider.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>().ContentRootPath;
    return new MyLibType(contentRoot);
});
```

Then inject this type in the constructor of the class you're planning to use it in. ASP.NET Core will resolve this type from the DI container and run the lambda that passes the content root to the library.

```cs
class MyController: ControllerBase
{
    private MyLibType _myLib;

    public MyController(MyLibType myLib)
    {
        _myLib = myLib; // MyLibType has been constructed with the content root path
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can hide this boilerplate behind an extension method on `IServiceCollection`:

```cs
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions {
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyLibrary(this IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddTransient<MyLibType>(provider => { ... });
        return services;
    }
}
```

Now the consumers of your library can simply do:

```cs
services.AddMyLibrary();
```

then consume it by injecting one of your types.